# 12.04 does not boot from the disk after installation

Tags: boot, raid, disk

Installed Ubuntu on HP xw4600 workstation using CD not USB. But after installation it does not boot from hard drive.
During installation it showed:

```
The entire disk will be used: /dev/mapper/isw_digjcabegb_Volume0(ext4) 250.1GB
Running “grub-install /dev/mapper”…
Error pop-up:
Unable to install GRUB in /dev/mapper
Executing ‘grub-install /dev/mapper’ failed. 
This is a fatal error.
```

Then another error:

```
Sorry, an error occurred and it was not possible to install the bootloader at the specified location.
How would you like to proceed?
Choose a different device to install the bootloader on:
/dev/mapper
```

I choose `/dev/mapper/isw_digjcabegb_Volume0` from the drop down menu and it gave me another error saying the at it failed again and this is a fatal error. Then it said installation complete and I need to restart the computer.